# Refactor promise javascript code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Basically, I have a code to approve an order code by applying Coupon entered by user into the Order transaction:

```
var Order = require('../models/order');
var Product = require('../models/product');
var Coupon = require('../models/coupon');

var _ = require('lodash');

exports.approveOrder = function(req, res) {
    var tempProducts;    
    var tempCoupon;
    var orderNbr = req.params.OrderNbr;
    if (orderNbr != undefined && orderNbr != '')
    {
        Order.findOne({ OrderNbr: orderNbr }).exec()
        .then(function(order) {
            if (order == undefined) {
                throw "Order " + orderNbr + " does not exist.";
            }
            else {
                if (order.OrderLines.length <= 0) throw "Ensure your Order has at least one order line.";

                if (req.body.CouponCode != undefined && req.body.CouponCode != '') {
                    // ***********************************************
                    // Want to refactor this following codes into some functions
                    // ***********************************************                  
                    Coupon.findOne({ CouponCode: req.body.CouponCode }).exec()
                    .then(function(coupon) {                        
                        if (coupon == undefined) {
                            throw "Coupon " + req.body.CouponCode + " does not exist.";
                        }
                        else {
                            if (coupon.Qty > 0 && (coupon.ValidFrom <= new Date() && coupon.ValidTo >= new Date())) {
                                coupon.Qty -= 1;
                                tempCoupon = coupon;

                                var prodNbrs = _.map(order.OrderLines, 'ProdNbr');
                                return Product.find({ ProdNbr: { $in : prodNbrs } }).exec();
                            }
                            else {
                                throw "Coupon " + coupon.CouponCode + " is not valid.";
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .then(function(products) {
                        var prodNbrs = _.map(order.OrderLines, 'ProdNbr');                                                
                        var totalQtyPerProd = 0;

                        _.forEach(products, function(product) {
                            totalQtyPerProd = _.sumBy(order.OrderLines, function(line) {
                                if (product.ProdNbr == line.ProdNbr) return line.Qty;
                            })
                            if (product.QtyOnHand - totalQtyPerProd < 0) throw "Product " + product.ProdNbr + " has insufficient quantity on hand.";

                            _.remove(prodNbrs, function(nbr) { return nbr == product.ProdNbr });
                            product.QtyOnHand -= totalQtyPerProd;

                            var totalDiscount = tempCoupon.Value / order.OrderLines.length;
                            if (tempCoupon.IsPercentage) {
                                totalDiscount = 1 - (tempCoupon.Value / 100);
                            }

                            _.forEach(order.OrderLines, function(line) {
                                if (line.ProdNbr == product.ProdNbr) {
                                    line.UnitPrice = product.UnitPrice;

                                    line.Amount = (line.Qty * line.UnitPrice) - totalDiscount;
                                    if (line.Amount < 0) line.Amount = 0;
                                    if (tempCoupon.IsPercentage) {
                                        line.Amount = (line.Qty * line.UnitPrice) * totalDiscount;
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        })

                        if (prodNbrs.length > 0) throw "Product " + prodNbrs[0] + " does not exist.";

                        tempProducts = products;

                        order.CouponCode = tempCoupon.CouponCode;
                        order.Status = 'S';
                        return order.save();
                    })
                    .then(function() {
                        return tempCoupon.save();
                    })
                    .then(function() {
                        _.forEach(tempProducts, function(product) {
                            product.save()
                            .then(function() {

                            })
                            .catch(function(err) {
                                if (err) res.status('500').jsonp({ error: err });
                            });
                        })
                        res.status('200').jsonp({ information: "Order "+ order.OrderNbr +" has been submitted successfully." });
                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        if (err) res.status('500').jsonp({ error: err });
                    });
                }
            }            
        }) 
        .catch(function(err) {
            if (err) res.status('500').jsonp({ error: err });
        });
    }
    else {
        res.status('500').jsonp({ error: "Order Number must be specified." });
    }
};
```

I want to split code each 'then' clause into some functions:

1. find Coupon and then return a Coupon.
2. update the order lines amount
3. update the coupon
4. return confirmation message

I tried using local variable to keep found Coupon, unfortunately the variable will be undefined if it is out of findOne() method, so in this code I used so many and long '.then' in findOne()

Any idea?

Comment: I think you should use async.waterfall() which runs an array of functions in series, each passing their results to the next in the array. However, if any of the functions pass an error to the callback, the next function is not executed and the main callback is immediately called with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to use the "then chain" is fine.
I would refactor the code creating separated functions to use in the chain like this:

```
var saveProducts = function() {
                        _.forEach(tempProducts, function(product) {
                            product.save()
                            .then(function() {

                            })
                            .catch(function(err) {
                                if (err) res.status('500').jsonp({ error: err });
                            });
                        })
                        res.status('200').jsonp({ information: "Order "+ order.OrderNbr +" has been submitted successfully." });
                    }

var saveCoupon = function() {
                        return tempCoupon.save();
                    }

var products = function(products) {
                        var prodNbrs = _.map(order.OrderLines, 'ProdNbr');                                                
                        var totalQtyPerProd = 0;

                        _.forEach(products, function(product) {
                            totalQtyPerProd = _.sumBy(order.OrderLines, function(line) {
                                if (product.ProdNbr == line.ProdNbr) return line.Qty;
                            })
                            if (product.QtyOnHand - totalQtyPerProd < 0) throw "Product " + product.ProdNbr + " has insufficient quantity on hand.";

                            _.remove(prodNbrs, function(nbr) { return nbr == product.ProdNbr });
                            product.QtyOnHand -= totalQtyPerProd;

                            var totalDiscount = tempCoupon.Value / order.OrderLines.length;
                            if (tempCoupon.IsPercentage) {
                                totalDiscount = 1 - (tempCoupon.Value / 100);
                            }

                            _.forEach(order.OrderLines, function(line) {
                                if (line.ProdNbr == product.ProdNbr) {
                                    line.UnitPrice = product.UnitPrice;

                                    line.Amount = (line.Qty * line.UnitPrice) - totalDiscount;
                                    if (line.Amount < 0) line.Amount = 0;
                                    if (tempCoupon.IsPercentage) {
                                        line.Amount = (line.Qty * line.UnitPrice) * totalDiscount;
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        })

                        if (prodNbrs.length > 0) throw "Product " + prodNbrs[0] + " does not exist.";

                        tempProducts = products;

                        order.CouponCode = tempCoupon.CouponCode;
                        order.Status = 'S';
                        return order.save();
                    }

var getProducts = function(coupon) {                        
                        if (coupon == undefined) {
                            throw "Coupon " + req.body.CouponCode + " does not exist.";
                        }
                        else {
                            if (coupon.Qty > 0 && (coupon.ValidFrom <= new Date() && coupon.ValidTo >= new Date())) {
                                coupon.Qty -= 1;
                                tempCoupon = coupon;

                                var prodNbrs = _.map(order.OrderLines, 'ProdNbr');
                                return Product.find({ ProdNbr: { $in : prodNbrs } }).exec();
                            }
                            else {
                                throw "Coupon " + coupon.CouponCode + " is not valid.";
                            }
                        }
                    }

exports.approveOrder = function(req, res) {
    var tempProducts;    
    var tempCoupon;
    var orderNbr = req.params.OrderNbr;
    if (orderNbr != undefined && orderNbr != '')
    {
        Order.findOne({ OrderNbr: orderNbr }).exec()
        .then(function(order) {
            if (order == undefined) {
                throw "Order " + orderNbr + " does not exist.";
            }
            else {
                if (order.OrderLines.length <= 0) throw "Ensure your Order has at least one order line.";

                if (req.body.CouponCode != undefined && req.body.CouponCode != '') {
                    // ***********************************************
                    // Want to refactor this following codes into some functions
                    // ***********************************************                  
                    Coupon.findOne({ CouponCode: req.body.CouponCode }).exec()
                    .then(getProducts)
                    .then(products)
                    .then(saveCoupon)
                    .then(saveProducts)
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        if (err) res.status('500').jsonp({ error: err });
                    });
                }
            }            
        }) 
        .catch(function(err) {
            if (err) res.status('500').jsonp({ error: err });
        });
    }
    else {
        res.status('500').jsonp({ error: "Order Number must be specified." });
    }
};
```

the result of each functions will be passed to the next in the chain

I suggest this thread on the best practices for promises

https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/216

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you make use of the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library with the waterfall method. Essentially it will allow you to have a more flat structure without the nesting by using callbacks.

Something like this:

```
var async = require('async');

var findCoupons = function(cb) {
    //do something
    cb(null, 'success');
}

var updateOrders = function(data, cb) {
    //do something
    console.log(data); //success
    cb(null, 'etc.');
}

...

async.waterfall([
    findCoupons,
    updateOrders,
    updateCoupon,
    confirmMessage
], function(err, result) {
    //all functions have finished running, do something.
});
```